# Using dbtype.structure with SubSonic 2?

Tags: stored-procedures, data-structures, subsonic, dbtype

When sending data to a stored procedure through SubSonic, how can I pass a dbtype.structure?

I have a TVP defined as READONLY, and when SubSonic generates the StoredProcedures.cs file, the parameter shows up as a string type.

What is the way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically rolled my own: [SubSonic 2.x StoredProcedure parameter data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970719/subsonic-2-x-storedprocedure-parameter-data-types)