# SubSonic 2.x StoredProcedure parameter data types?

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic, parameters, types, sqldbtype

From what I can see, SubSonic 2.x stored procedure parameter data types can only be of type System.Data.DbType.

Is there a quick way to add System.Data.SqlDbType so we can use System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured to pass tables - ultimately to TVP's?

In this particular project, all data caller functions are accessed through StoredProcedures.cs.  If we switched to 3.x, does it support SqlDbType.Structured, and if so, is it a seamless integration to retain the current StoredProcedures.cs methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I created my own solution for this - [SubSonic 2.x now supports TVP's - SqlDbType.Structure / DataTables for SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999570/subsonic-2-x-now-supports-tvps-sqldbtype-structure-datatables-for-sql-server)

I'm somewhat surprised at the lack of response to TVP's, and seemingly low traction TVP's have  in online communities.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970719/subsonic-2-x-storedprocedure-parameter-data-types). Some guy with the same username and an identical avatar image just implemented that ;)