# SubSonic 2.x now supports TVP's - SqlDbType.Structure / DataTables for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, subsonic, datatable, structured-data

For those interested, I have now modified the SubSonic 2.x code to recognize and support DataTable parameter types.

You can read more about SQL Server 2008 features here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/9/0/4906f81b-eb1a-49c3-bb05-ff3bcbb5d5ae/SQL%20SERVER%202008-RDBMS/T-SQL%20Enhancements%20with%20SQL%20Server%202008%20-%20Praveen%20Srivatsav.pdf

What this enhancement will now allow you to do is to create a partial StoredProcedures.cs class, with a method that overrides the stored procedure wrapper method.

A bit about good form:
My DAL has no direct table access, and my DB only has execute permissions for that user to my sprocs.  As such, SubSonic only generates the AllStructs and StoredProcedures classes.

**The SPROC:**

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testInsertToTestTVP]
    @UserDetails TestTVP READONLY,
    @Result INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @Result = -1

    --SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_TestTVP] ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_TestTVP]
            ( [GroupInsertID], [FirstName], [LastName] )
    SELECT [GroupInsertID], [FirstName], [LastName]
    FROM @UserDetails

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 1
            SELECT @Result
            RETURN @Result
        END
    --SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_TestTVP] OFF

END
```

**The TVP:**

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestTVP] AS TABLE(
    [GroupInsertID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

The the auto gen tool runs, it creates the following erroneous method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an object wrapper for the testInsertToTestTVP Procedure
    /// </summary>
    public static StoredProcedure TestInsertToTestTVP(string UserDetails, int? Result)
    {
        SubSonic.StoredProcedure sp = new SubSonic.StoredProcedure("testInsertToTestTVP", DataService.GetInstance("MyDAL"), "dbo");     
        sp.Command.AddParameter("@UserDetails", UserDetails, DbType.AnsiString, null, null);
        sp.Command.AddOutputParameter("@Result", DbType.Int32, 0, 10);            
        return sp;
    }
```

It sets UserDetails as type string.

As it's good form to have two folders for a SubSonic DAL - Custom and Generated, I created a StoredProcedures.cs partial class in Custom that looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an object wrapper for the testInsertToTestTVP Procedure
    /// </summary>
    public static StoredProcedure TestInsertToTestTVP(DataTable dt, int? Result)
    {
        SubSonic.StoredProcedure sp = new SubSonic.StoredProcedure("testInsertToTestTVP", 
                                                                    DataService.GetInstance("MyDAL"), 
                                                                    "dbo");

        // TODO: Modify the SubSonic code base in sp.Command.AddParameter to accept
        //       a parameter type of System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured, as it currently only accepts
        //       System.Data.DbType.
        //sp.Command.AddParameter("@UserDetails", dt, System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured null, null);

        sp.Command.AddParameter("@UserDetails", dt, SqlDbType.Structured);
        sp.Command.AddOutputParameter("@Result", DbType.Int32, 0, 10);

        return sp;
    }
```

As you can see, the method signature now contains a DataTable, and with my modification to the SubSonic framework, this now works perfectly.

I'm wondering if the SubSonic guys can modify the auto-gen to recognize a TVP in a sproc signature, as to avoid having to re-write the wrapper?

Does SubSonic 3.x support Structured data types?

Also, I'm sure many will be interested in using this code, so where can I upload the new code?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a question in here anywhere?

Comment: @Sean: several question actually. They are addressed to SubSonic maintainers, but they are valid questions.

Comment: It's true that the post does contain some questions. However, in it's current form, this seems more like a patch/feature submission directed at a small number of specific recipients, as opposed to a general purpose question that would be useful to a typical Stack Overflow reader. I guess it just doesn't really "feel like" a usual Stack Overflow question to me. Is there perhaps a way to rewrite or reorganize this submission so that it's closer to the normal theme of the site?

Comment: @Sean: the main problem is that subsonic dropped it's forum and sent people here. This post might be better on codeproject of course.

Comment: @ElHaix: Do you mind sharing the changes that you made to QueryCommand.cs and any other classes that you had to modify to support Table-Valued parameters?

Comment: @Joel:  I will post a link for you this weekend once the code finds a home.

Comment: @ElHaix: Did your code ever find a home?  I would love to have a look at your work on this subject.

Comment: @Joe:  CodePlex project and documentation found here: http://subsonic23tvp.codeplex.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted a CodePlex project with the entire solution, source code and instructions.

The project can be found [here](http://subsonic23tvp.codeplex.com).

Comment: Updated the code on CodePlex - added support for SOAP object references.